# Displaying questions as array one after another

Tags: javascript, php

I am doing a scramble game. I will like to ask how am I suppose to display one question after another when one question is correct, then show the second question. It is a html5 game, which include of using php, javascript and css. If my database have 10 rows. After the first question is correct, how can I retrieve the next question? I have a problem in the array in php too.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Scramble Game</title>
</head>

<body>
<header>
<center>

<h1>Drag in order</h1>

<?php
$conn = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "password");

if (!mysql_select_db("login")) {
echo "Unable to select go database " . mysql_error();
exit;
}


$sql = "select * from sen order by id";

$result = mysql_query($sql);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
//If my database have 10 rows
 $output = array();
for ( $row["full"] = 0;  $row["full"] < $count;  $row["full"]++) {
$ouput[ $row["full"]] = array
    ( $ouput[ $row["full"]]
    );
}

}

mysql_free_result($result);


?>

//will display the actual sentence
<div id="adiv" style="font:24px bold; display:block"><p id="demo"></p></div>

<script>
js_var = "<?php echo $output ?>";
var c = ['c1','c2','c3','c4','c5','c6','c7','c8','c9','c10'];
var div_id = ['id1','id2','id3','id4','id5','id6','id7','id8','id9','id10'];
var box_id = ['box1','box2','box3','box4','box5','box6','box7','box8','box9','box10'];
var original = js_var.split("#");
var balls90= js_var.split("#");

var org_txt="";
for (i=0;i<balls90.length;i++){
org_txt=org_txt.concat(original[i]);
}

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =  org_txt;

function getNumbers() {
var player1 = new Array();
balls90.sort(function() {
    return Math.random() - .25;
    document.getElementById("btn_shuffle").onclick = function(){displayDate()};
});


 for (var i = 0; i < balls90.length; i++) {
     document.writeln('<div id='+box_id[i]+' class=box droppable=true ondrop=drop(event)     
ondragover=allowDrop(event)></div>');
 }


for (var i = 0; i < balls90.length; i++) {
    player1.push(balls90[i]);

    document.writeln('<div id='+div_id[i]+' draggable=true droppable=true 
ondragstart=drag(event)>'+balls90[i]+'</div>');
}

}

getNumbers();



function dragWord(dragEvent){
dragEvent.dataTransfer.setData("text/html",     
dragEvent.target.textContent+"|"+dragEvent.target.parentNode.id);
}


function dropWord(dropEvent){
var dropData = dropEvent.dataTransfer.getData("text/html");
var dropItems = dropData.split("|");
var prevElem = document.getElementById(dropItems[1]);
prevElem.getElementsByTagName("div")[0].textContent = dropEvent.target.textContent;
dropEvent.target.textContent = dropItems[0];
dropEvent.preventDefault();
}

function allowDrop(ev) {
ev.preventDefault();
}  


function drag(ev) {
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("Text", ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
    ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
  var match = 0;

 var result = true;
 for (var i=0; i<original.length; ++i) {
 if (original[i] !== $("#box"+(i+1)).text()) {
 result = false;
 break;
 }
 }

//After the first question is correct, it will go to the next question from the database

 if(result) {
 alert('correct');
 document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = $output[i]; 

 } 
 this.print();
 }).call(output[i], i);
 }
 }
 </script>
 <center><button onclick='getNumbers()'>SCRAMBLE</button></center>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: What's in your database exactly?
PD: 
To output a php variable into your js script you must first do json_encode($output);

Comment: In my database there is two columns, id and full. Full is the one that store the full sentence. My game is Scramble so I have use a function split to split the words out using a delimiter which is "#". So for example id 1, in full column id 1 is "How #are #you?"

Comment: @Daniel Li  Saw that you have solve such similar questions, I have tried to apply on it but not working. Can you help me? :)